# Unable to get the Count of a returned IEnumerable in an Asychronous method

Tags: wpf, wcf, mvvm

I am completely new to this but trying to learn. I'm sure there is a simple answer but I don't know enough to Google the right problem. I'm sure this must be a common problem.

In using Visual Studio 2010, WPF , .net 4.0, on a MVVM pattern using a WCF service, I have this which works perfectly:

```
 private void RefreshEncountertimes()
    {
        // consume the WCF service.
        this.dataservice.GetEncounterDetailsCompleted += (s, e) =>
            {
                this.Encounterdetails = e.Result;
             };
           // call the WCF service
        this.dataservice.GetEncounterDetailsAsync(Calendardate);
    }
```

where Encounterdetails is:

```
    private IEnumerable<EncounterDetail> encounterdetails;
    public IEnumerable<EncounterDetail> Encounterdetails
    {
        get
        {
            return this.encounterdetails;
        }
        set
        {
            this.encounterdetails = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("Encounterdetails");
        }
    }
```

However, when trying to get the count on the returned Encounterdetails like this:

```
  // search for encounters of the calendardate
    private void RefreshEncountertimes()
    {
        // consume the WCF service.
        this.dataservice.GetEncounterDetailsCompleted += (s, e) =>
            {
                this.Encounterdetails = e.Result;
                this.ListCount = Encounterdetails.Count();   //<---CRASHES WITH INFINITIE LOOP
            };

        // call the WCF service
        this.dataservice.GetEncounterDetailsAsync(Calendardate);
    }
```

where ListCount is:

```
 private int listcount;
    public int ListCount
    {
        get
        {
            return listcount;
        }
        set
        {
            this.listcount = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ListCount");
            CanFindPatient = ListCount > 0; 
        }
    }
```

It crashes with:
    Cannot evaluate expression because the current thread is in a stack overflow state.

So how do you get the Count of a returned IEnumerable from an asynchronous procedure?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What triggers `RefreshEncountertimes`?

Comment: How do you even... get Count from IEnumerable<T> ?

Comment: @MikkoViitala: Linq extension method, jeez.  OP, you need to catch the exception, call ToString on it, and [edit] your question to add the details.  Without the call stack there isn't enough info here to tell.  Also, you could just put a breakpoint in there and see why it's being called recursively.  Simplest thing ever to debug, stackoverflows...

Comment: @ReedCopsey   private DateTime? calendardate;
        public DateTime? Calendardate
        {
            get
            {
                return this.calendardate;
            }
            set
            {
                if ((Calendardate != null) || !Calendardate.Equals(value))
                {
                    this.calendardate = value;
                    this.OnPropertyChanged("Calendardate");
                    this.RefreshEncountertimes();         
                }
            }
        }

Comment: @Will I tried with a breakpoint, it still crashed with a stack overflow without telling me why.

Comment: @Will the stack shows: Nova5.FullClient.exe!Nova5.UI.ViewModels.DoctorDesk.vmDoctorDesk.CanFindPatient.set(bool value) Line 293 + 0xffffffec bytes

Comment: @AlanWayne Something is causing a "loop" so it keeps calling this.  Likely something's listening to a property changed, that's triggerring `Calendardate` to be set when `RefreshEncountertimes` runs...

Comment: @ReedCopsey Found it. Very difficult to debug. CanFindPatient {get; set;} was defined incorrectly. Don't know why this should cause a loop, but fixing it stopped the loop. Thanks. Your suggestion at least let me know that IEnumerable.Count() is legal inside the asynchronous completed event.